# after I fork a github project, how can I stay current with the original project?

Tags: github

On github, after I fork a project, modify it, then submit my pull request, it seems that I have to delete and re-fork in order to stay current with any changes made after my pull request is honored.

It seems tedious to have to keep deleting the repo to keep it current. Is there some way to keep it current without deleting and re-forking?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should add the original project as a remote to your working copy. Then you can pull changes from the original repository and push them to your forked repository. The commands for this look something like:

```
git remote add upstream <original repo url>
git pull upstream master
git push origin
```

Comment: @metaperl does have a point though for anyone from github passing through, it would be nice to be able to do this from within github interface?

Comment: Why it needs to be done locally is to handle potential conflicts. Once you have forked and committed stuff your repo is different from the original. Even if they accept your pull they might not pull all the commits just cherry pick. To make sure your HEAD is exactly the same, rename your master and create a new master from upstream/master

Comment: This is very good to know. I would like to update my forks to include personal code in certain projects but I also want to keep updated with the original master. It's too bad that the Github clients that they provide don't allow this functionality. I found a thread that gives GUI clients which can handle this functionality. http://superuser.com/a/436508/135890

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a pull request in your forked repo by comparing to the original repository and then merge it in your repository.