# Can/should you reuse a GitHub Pull Request?

Tags: github

I just did my first pull request for a GitHub project that had part of my changes accepted and was then closed by the owner of the repo I forked.  I want to make another change for that repo, but I'm unsure how to proceed.   Since my pull request was accepted and closed, do I need to delete my fork and then create a new one?  Or is there a way to refresh my fork to pull in the new changes from the master?  Or should I simply just manually copy the changes into my forked project and then put my new changes on top of it?  Thanks for any advice/direction.

G

Comment: See thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767605/after-i-fork-a-github-project-how-can-i-stay-current-with-the-original-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is a short answer, but to keep things clean, you should fork again.  All the history from your current branch is already covered so there's no need to keep all that around.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response!  What is the process for that?  I see how in the admin section there is a place where I can delete my forked repo.  Should I just do that and then delete the directories on my local machine?  Or is there a different mechanism I should follow that is cleaner?

Comment: I don't think you need to delete the fork that is on the server, just create a new repo on your local machine and start fresh from there.